# How can I use AES-256 encryption on Google App Engine?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, encryption, aes

It looks like I'm limited to 128-bit AES encryption on GAE. The following code throws InvalidKeyException (Illegal key size), looks like this happens when unlimited security policy is not installed.

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES"); 
SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(new byte[64], "AES"); // 256 bit key for AES      
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

Anyone know about this?

Comment: According to this, it can't be done: http://code.google.com/p/memwords/wiki/Gotchas#Google_App_Engine_and_AES-256

Comment: Any 256 bit alternatives to AES that work on GAE?

Comment: Just use 128 bit AES. By the way, you do know that 64 bytes is 512 bits, right?

Comment: yup that was an old line of code. My security team mate is telling me that we'll eventually have to implement 256 anyways. Are there any alternatives to AES that GAE supports for 256 or is that a hard cipher limitation set by Google?

Comment: Possible alternatives to AES are Rijndael, Twofish or Serpent.  AES is Rijndael with a 128 bit block size, pure Rijndael may allow different block and key sizes.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1612), you can use BouncyCastle with GAE.